# VBA Code lags - How can i quicken it?

Tags: vba, excel

Any help would be appreciated on this

I have the following code which looks through worksheets on workbook 1 with a certain name(E.g, SheetA, Sheetb, etc). After the sheet matches, if a certain critieria matches on the select sheet, it will start copying values from the sheet from workbook 1 and paste them into workbook 2.

I want the data from workbook 1 to write under existing data in workbook 2, not overwrite, which is what it's doing. however, my code right now is doing the copy/paste one by one.

I'm told I can quicken it if I save the values into variables and write them into cells, however I'm not sure how to go about it

```
Public Sub Validation()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim iCounter As Long
    Dim wkb1 As Workbook
    Dim wkb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim rw1 As Long
    Dim rw2 As Long
    Dim rw3 As Long
    Dim rw4 As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim WS2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim ws4 As Worksheet
    Dim ws5 As Worksheet
    Dim ws6 As Worksheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("workbook2xlsx")
    Set WS2 = wkb2.Sheets("sheeta")
    Set ws3 = wkb2.Sheets("sheetb")
    Set ws4 = wkb2.Sheets("sheetc")
    Set ws5 = wkb2.Sheets("sheetd")
    Set ws6 = wkb2.Sheets("sheetf")
    rw = WS2.Cells(WS2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    rw1 = ws3.Cells(ws3.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    rw2 = ws4.Cells(ws4.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    rw3 = ws5.Cells(ws5.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    rw4 = ws6.Cells(ws6.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Set wkb1 = ThisWorkbook
    wkb1.Activate

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like "*" & "sheeta" & "*" Then
            ws.Select
            If ws.Cells(5, 2).Value = "COMPLETE" Then
                Cells(9, 1).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(29, 2).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(29, 3).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(15, 1).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(39, 1).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(39, 2).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(39, 3).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 7).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(55, 1).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 8).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(55, 2).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(55, 3).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 10).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(55, 4).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 11).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Cells(57, 1).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 12).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(57, 2).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 13).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(57, 3).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 14).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(57, 4).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 15).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(59, 1).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 16).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(59, 2).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 17).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(59, 3).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 18).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(59, 4).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 19).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Cells(61, 1).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 20).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(61, 2).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 21).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(3, 2).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 22).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(4, 2).Copy
                WS2.Cells(rw, 23).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            End If

        End If

        If ws.Name Like "*" & "sheetb" & "*" Then
            ws.Select
            If ws.Cells(5, 2).Value = "COMPLETE" Then

                Cells(9, 1).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(9, 2).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(26, 1).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(14, 1).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(26, 2).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(26, 3).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(30, 4).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 7).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(32, 4).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 8).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Cells(46, 1).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(46, 2).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 10).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(46, 3).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 11).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(46, 4).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 12).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Cells(48, 1).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 13).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(48, 2).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 14).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(48, 3).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 15).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(48, 4).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 16).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Cells(50, 1).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 17).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(50, 2).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 18).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(50, 3).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 19).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(50, 4).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 20).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Cells(52, 4).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 21).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Cells(3, 2).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 22).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(4, 2).Copy
                ws3.Cells(rw1, 23).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            End If
        End If

        If ws.Name Like "*" & "sheetc" & "*" Then
            ws.Select
            If ws.Cells(5, 2).Value = "COMPLETE" Then

                Cells(9, 1).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(9, 3).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(9, 2).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(23, 1).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(19, 2).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(19, 3).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(13, 1).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 7).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(13, 2).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 8).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Cells(33, 1).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(33, 2).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 10).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(33, 3).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 11).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(33, 4).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 12).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Cells(35, 1).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 13).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(35, 2).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 14).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(35, 3).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 15).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(35, 4).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 16).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Cells(37, 1).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 17).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(37, 2).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 18).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(37, 3).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 19).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(37, 4).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 20).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Cells(39, 4).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 21).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Cells(3, 2).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 22).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(4, 2).Copy
                ws4.Cells(rw2, 23).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            End If
        End If

        If ws.Name Like "*" & "sheetd" & "*" Then
            ws.Select
            If ws.Cells(5, 2).Value = "COMPLETE" Then

                Cells(9, 1).Copy
                ws5.Cells(rw3, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(9, 2).Copy
                ws5.Cells(rw3, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(9, 4).Copy
                ws5.Cells(rw3, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(13, 1).Copy
                ws5.Cells(rw3, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(13, 2).Copy
                ws5.Cells(rw3, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(13, 3).Copy
                ws5.Cells(rw3, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Cells(21, 1).Copy
                ws5.Cells(rw3, 7).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


                Cells(17, 1).Copy
                ws5.Cells(rw3, 8).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(17, 2).Copy
                ws5.Cells(rw3, 9).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(17, 3).Copy
                ws5.Cells(rw3, 10).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Cells(3, 2).Copy
                ws5.Cells(rw3, 11).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(4, 2).Copy
                ws5.Cells(rw3, 12).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            End If
        End If

        If ws.Name Like "*" & "Sheetf" & "*" Then
            ws.Select
            If ws.Cells(5, 2).Value = "COMPLETE" Then

                Cells(9, 1).Copy
                ws6.Cells(rw4, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(9, 2).Copy
                ws6.Cells(rw4, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(9, 3).Copy
                ws6.Cells(rw4, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(11, 1).Copy
                ws6.Cells(rw4, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(15, 2).Copy
                ws6.Cells(rw4, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(15, 3).Copy
                ws6.Cells(rw4, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Cells(3, 2).Copy
                ws5.Cells(rw3, 7).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Cells(4, 2).Copy
                ws5.Cells(rw3, 8).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            End If
        End If

    Next ws

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I just posted an Answer.  In it I assumed that the last two copy operations were typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning off Application.Calculations, eliminating selections and reducing the number of writes by using arrays will speed up your code.

```
Sub AppendRow(ws As Worksheet, ParamArray Args())
    With ws
        With .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .Resize(1, UBound(Args(), 1) + 1) = Args
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub ToggleEvents(EnableEvents As Boolean)
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = EnableEvents
        .EnableEvents = EnableEvents
        .ScreenUpdating = EnableEvents
        .Calculation = IIf(EnableEvents, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub Validation()
    ToggleEvents False
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wkb1 As Workbook: Set wkb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wkb2 As Workbook: Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("workbook2xlsx")
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            If .Cells(5, 2).Value = "COMPLETE" Then
                If .Name Like "*sheeta*" Then
                    AppendRow wkb2.Worksheets("sheeta"), .Cells(9, 1), .Cells(29, 2), .Cells(29, 3), .Cells(15, 1), .Cells(39, 1), .Cells(39, 2), .Cells(39, 3), .Cells(55, 1), .Cells(55, 2), .Cells(55, 3), .Cells(55, 4), .Cells(57, 1), .Cells(57, 2), .Cells(57, 3), .Cells(57, 4), .Cells(59, 1), .Cells(59, 2), .Cells(59, 3), .Cells(59, 4), .Cells(61, 1), .Cells(61, 2), .Cells(3, 2), .Cells(4, 2)
                ElseIf .Name Like "*sheetb*" Then
                    AppendRow wkb2.Worksheets("sheetb"), .Cells(9, 1), .Cells(9, 2), .Cells(26, 1), .Cells(14, 1), .Cells(26, 2), .Cells(26, 3), .Cells(30, 4), .Cells(32, 4), .Cells(46, 1), .Cells(46, 2), .Cells(46, 3), .Cells(46, 4), .Cells(48, 1), .Cells(48, 2), .Cells(48, 3), .Cells(48, 4), .Cells(50, 1), .Cells(50, 2), .Cells(50, 3), .Cells(50, 4), .Cells(52, 4), .Cells(3, 2), .Cells(4, 2)
                ElseIf .Name Like "*sheetc*" Then
                    AppendRow wkb2.Worksheets("sheetc"), .Cells(9, 1), .Cells(9, 3), .Cells(9, 2), .Cells(23, 1), .Cells(19, 2), .Cells(19, 3), .Cells(13, 1), .Cells(13, 2), .Cells(33, 1), .Cells(33, 2), .Cells(33, 3), .Cells(33, 4), .Cells(35, 1), .Cells(35, 2), .Cells(35, 3), .Cells(35, 4), .Cells(37, 1), .Cells(37, 2), .Cells(37, 3), .Cells(37, 4), .Cells(39, 4), .Cells(3, 2), .Cells(4, 2)
                ElseIf .Name Like "*sheetd*" Then
                    AppendRow wkb2.Worksheets("sheetd"), .Cells(9, 1), .Cells(9, 2), .Cells(9, 4), .Cells(13, 1), .Cells(13, 2), .Cells(13, 3), .Cells(21, 1), .Cells(17, 1), .Cells(17, 2), .Cells(17, 3), .Cells(3, 2), .Cells(4, 2)
                ElseIf .Name Like "*sheetf*" Then
                    AppendRow wkb2.Worksheets("Sheetf"), .Cells(9, 1), .Cells(9, 2), .Cells(9, 3), .Cells(11, 1), .Cells(15, 2), .Cells(15, 3), .Cells(3, 2), .Cells(4, 2)
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
    ToggleEvents True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the help. I'm wondering - it looks like it's pulling data from prenamed sheets - e.g. for 'sheeta', pull these cells, paste. The workbook i'm working with requires Excel to account for all sheets named similar to 'sheeta' - i.e. 'sheeta(1)' to 'sheeta(n)' as there can be duplicate sheets with the same name but with a (n) at the end

Comment: I tested the code above and get 'Compile Error: invalid or unqualified reference'. I also tried to tweak the code to look for sheets with similar name, instead of with activeworkbook.worksheets I used " If ws.Name Like "*" & "Sheetf" & "*" Then
            ws.Select", couldn't get it to work

Comment: Yeah haha, good catch! The addition of xlcalculationmanual to my current code cuts it to 6 seconds, not quick but not slow, will try to work with what you provided to get it down more, thanks for your help :)

Comment: I just updated my answer.  This time I extracted the cells from your code programmably  to avoid mistakes.  Let me know how it works.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! It looks like the appendrow sub is the biggest part in the code

Comment: Not sure how it works exactly but it sure is quick, run time is 2 seconds versus 6 sec with my caveman method